# SQL Server merge rows method

Tags: sql-server, merge

What is the best way to merge rows if it is null or same text in below table ?

```
    RequestID   ItemNo  ManagerApprovalDate     HRApprovalDate      ACCApprovalDate
    PCM0000152  1         9/6/2017 14:31         NULL               NULL
    PCM0000152  2            NULL                NULL              22/6/2017 13:52
    PCM0000152  1            NULL                NULL              22/6/2017 13:52
  PCM0000152    2         9/6/2017 14:31         NULL              NULL
```

What I want :

```
   RequestID    ItemNo  ManagerApprovalDate HRApprovalDate  ACCApprovalDate
   PCM0000152   1       9/6/2017 14:31          NULL        22/6/2017 13:52
   PCM0000152   2       9/6/2017 14:31          NULL        22/6/2017 13:52
```

PK : RequestID,Itemno

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want aggregation not merge:

```
select requestid, itemno,
       max(ManagerApprovalDate) as ManagerApprovalDate,
       max(HRApprovalDate) as HRApprovalDate,
       max(ACCApprovalDate) as ACCApprovalDate
from t
group by requestid, itemno;
```